# How would you code this: Grid-breaking shapes

Tags: html, css, image

I'm a person that learns best from example. Currently, I'm diving into the field of Web Development after fifteen years of developing desktop apps. I'm still getting used to all the web technologies used for developing modern web sites and everywhere I look, I see cool little UI elements and question how they're implemented. So I thought I'd ask you, the web experts...the wexperts :)

What are some straight forward or creative ways you could code this grid-breaking arrow...

[image]

The basic layout for this page looks like...

[image]

1. What would the html/css code look like?
2. Would you split the image into multiple images or could you use a single image?

I'm sure this is a really simple concept and it completely boggles me.  I'm sorry if this is a strange question, remember I'm a noob! :)

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Here's a [link](http://psdtuts.com/tutorials/interface-tutorials/how-a-simple-layout-can-be-mixed-n-matched-with-patterns-photos-and-backgrounds/) to the original tutorial where I found these images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your mockup the Header Panel includes the height from the top of the green box to the bottom of the box.

```
background: green url(images/header-bottom.jpg) no-repeat bottom left;
```

That jpg file includes that last 70 of so pixels in height including the whole arrow. Since your header and navigation are below where that arrow goes the containers will be exactly how you show it.

This also enables you to have Submenu and Content to just have background colors since the only gradient you seem to have in those two regions are in the same zone as the arrow in Header Panel.

Comment: If you wanted to make the background interchangeable you could use a png instead of merging the background into the Header Panel background.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a rectangle image which is wide and short to handle it. Use the same colors as the rest of the page so that it blends in. Check it in all browsers to make sure the image renders the same as the html colors. With some image formats this is not the case at least in some browsers.

Comment: Good point about the colors. If you use make sure not to embed a color profile into your image you should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this... there are two or three ways that are better than most.

Here is an image of what Ballsacian and Sean are talking about. Ignore the black bits of the top of text on the bottom, imprecise screenshot taking on my part.

[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/9392/picture6e.png](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/9392/picture6e.png)

You can make the green part of the arrow transparent and save it as a gif or png, since the slope appears to be 45 degrees (no jaggies in GIF). You would still have to edit the image to match the subnav and content background colors if you ever change them, but the transparent triangle will automatically show the header background color through.

You would also have to remove the margins between the header, subnav, and content containers.

The Photoshop guy who made this clearly wanted the background to show through "naturally" by making the margins between the header and subnav/content, but that is impossible without un-semantic markup with the arrow. The way you could do this without even using CSS is to just put the image in right after the header, in between the header and subnav/content.

```
<header>
<img src="arrow.gif" />
<section class="subnav" />
<section class="content" />
```

Then make the line be transparent instead of the arrow. Now you would have to change the image if you ever changed the header, subnav, or content background-colors, but not the body background-color. This accomplishes what the Photoshop guy wanted in spirit, but is ultimately not as satisfying markup wise.

I can see that this concept is very awesome in photoshop, you only have to change the background colors of each of the sections and transparency takes care of the rest, cool! If you were confused as to how to do this and keep the Photoshop guy's concept true to itself, I don't blame you. It is impossible to do with basic HTML and CSS with images. Maybe with SVG you can do it.

For fun, here is the super-optimized sprite way of doing it. This requires you to put in a huge vertical transparent space between the arrow and the content top gradient. Then use this background on the UL of the subnav and the div/section of the content container. Set the background-position to 0 -(verticalspace + arrowheight) and repeat-x for the content. 3k single http request.

[alt text http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/8503/arrowy.gif](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/8503/arrowy.gif)